# C++ return different objects

Tags: c++, database, oop, auto

i have a big problem.. I wonna select the Storage Service via a wrapper class. The returning value must be an object within the storage service class. I pasted my current approach. But my mindset didn't worked so far.

Error:

> error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: ‘SQL*’ and then ‘REDIS*’     return new REDIS();

The big wish is to have an interface class which defines the struct and some "driver classes" which contains all necessary operations for the target storage service.

I hope you have another approach, how I can solve this problem..

```
    #include <iostream>


class StorageTemplate {
    public:
        virtual bool UserhasSurName() = 0;
        virtual bool UserhasGivenName() = 0;
};

class SQL: public StorageTemplate {
    public:
        bool UserhasSurName() {
            //A SQL QUERY
            return true;
        }
        bool UserhasGivenName() {
            //AN ANOTHER SQL QUERY
            return true;
        }
};

class REDIS: public StorageTemplate {
    public:
        bool UserhasSurName() {
            //A REDIS CALL
            return false;
        }
        bool UserhasGivenName() {
            //A REDIS CALL
            return false;
        }
};


class controller {
    public:
        auto test(int select) {
            if( select == 1)
            {
                return new SQL(); 
            } else {
                return new REDIS();
            }
        }
};



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    controller cont;
    auto schnitzel = cont.test(1);
    auto mitzel = cont.test(2);
    std::cout << schnitzel->UserhasSurName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mitzel->UserhasSurName() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: 1) "_But my mindset didn't worked so far._" Such statement is useless. What about it, didn't work? 2) Please provide [mcve] (what is `hallo`?).

Comment: oh sorry this function is deprecated i mean UserhasSurName() -.-

Comment: It is not a good idea to use all uppercase identifiers.

Comment: thanks. but this isn't the problem...

Comment: `auto` cannot deduce base class pointer from two derived, do that explicitly, error is clear

Comment: @Slava i know, but i haven't any other approach... and i hope that someone else can help me and can give a tip / trick or an idea...

Comment: Just replace `auto` with `StorageTemplate *` and you better use smart pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is the following: Consider your function

```
auto test(int select) {
    if (select == 1) {
        return new SQL(); 
    } else {
        return new REDIS();
    }
}
```

If you trying to evaluate `test(1)` this expands to

```
auto test(int select) {
    if (true) {
        return new SQL(); 
    } else {
        return new REDIS();
    }
}
```

which results in a type error!

I show you three workarounds for your problem:

**1. Function template and `if constexpr`**

Make `test` a function template and check for the correct type using the C++17 feature `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T>
auto test() {
    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, SQL>::value) {
        return new SQL();
    } else {
        return new REDIS();
    }
}
```

Use it in `main()` like this:

```
int main(){
    controller cont;
    auto schnitzel = cont.test<SQL>();
    auto mitzel = cont.test<REDIS>();
    std::cout << schnitzel->UserhasSurName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mitzel->UserhasSurName() << std::endl;
}
```

**2. Function template and std::unique_ptr**

If you want to avoid using the `if constexpr` you can simply return an instance of `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer. This is the preferred way to do:

```
template<typename T>
auto test() {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T);
}
```

Alternatively you can just return `std::make_unique<T>()`.

**3. Returning an instance of the base class**

This is is most obvious solution to avoid the type error: Just return an instance of the base class. As above a solution using smart pointers is preferred here:

```
std::unique_ptr<StorageTemplate> test(const int select) {
    if (select == 1) {
        return std::make_unique<SQL>();
    } else {
        return std::make_unique<REDIS>();
    }
}
```

If you really want to avoid using smart pointers just use raw ones like this:

```
StorageTemplate* test(const int select) {
    if (select == 1) {
        return new SQL();
    } else {
        return new REDIS();
    }
}
```

Comment: `_StorageTemplate` - that's illegal

Comment: @datell wow thank you very much!. but when i run 3. (with the unique_ptr) i'm receiving the error "Parse failed"

Comment: @N.Men Please compile using ``-std=c++14``

Comment: @Slava What do you mean?

Comment: @datell i'm using the following command "g++ test.cpp -o output.run -std=c++14"

Comment: Such identifiers are reserved and cannot be used in user code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 0):

in this code

```
auto test(int select) {
    if( select == 1)
    {
        return new SQL(); 
    } else {
        return new REDIS();
    }
```

`auto` can't be deduced because it only match to exact type. so even if `SQL` and `REDIS` inherite from `StorageTemplate`, `StorageTemplate` won't be deduced. you need to spécifie the type

```
StorageTemplate* test(int select) {
    if( select == 1)
    {
        return new SQL(); 
    } else {
        return new REDIS();
    }
```

Comment: You should really use a smart pointer here, otherwise you have to remember in the call site to delete the pointer when done with it.

Comment: @NathanOliver i fully agree but i tryed to change OP's code as little as possible

Comment: Alternatively, he could static_cast each new object down to StorageTemplate*, but then what's the point of auto really..

Comment: Yes but OPs code has memory leak right there you should mention that in your answer

Comment: thanks!! Yeah i know smart pointers are better than raw c pointer.

Comment: @N.Men this error isn't coming from the code you have shown

Comment: @Slava on which location is a memory leak?

Comment: @N.Men you test function allocate with new but thoses pointers are never deleted

Comment: @N.Men memory leak is usually happens because of missing `delete`. Sorry I do not think it is theoretically possible to point exact location where `delete` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Error return `Auto` in test(),it's return two different types. Change by `StorageTemplate*`

```
class controller {
    public:
        StorageTemplate* test(int select) {
            if( select == 1)
            {
                return new SQL(); 
            } else {
                return new REDIS();
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: thanks!! But i'm getting a new error. Please see my post under Update 2

Comment: please look under my post "UPDATE 2" the error message is very short!